# Check-state counter is always zero

Tags: freebsd, ipfw

My firewall rules are:

```
00010      660      73050 allow ip from any to any via lo0
00011        0          0 deny ip from any to 127.0.0.0/8
00012        0          0 deny ip from 127.0.0.0/8 to any
00013        0          0 check-state
00100      131       4192 deny ip from any to any via sis0 keep-state
```

and so on.

Why is the `check-state` counter always zero? I thought this rule should match for dynamic rules. And I am sure there are.